# as3 if else, min max value

Tags: actionscript-3

I want a user to fill in a number ranging between 1-350 in a text field (INPUTFIELD).
Through an XML I want to return a string in another text field (OUTPUTFIELD).

I got 99% of it working, but after a user fills in a number 0 or higher than 350, I want to return a message in the OUTPUTFIELD.

**I do not get this to work and I get the message:**

```
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter text must be non-null.
    at flash.text::TextField/set text()
    at MethodInfo-2()
```

**My code is as follows:**

```
this.stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);
function keyDownHandler(event : KeyboardEvent):void {
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.ENTER) { 
        if (inputField.text > "0") {
               outputField.text = xmlData.prefix_list.country[Number(inputField.text)];
               outputField.setTextFormat(myTextFormat);
        } else {
               if (inputField.text > "350") {
                   outputField.text = "DOES NOT EXIST";
                   outputField.setTextFormat(myTextFormat);
               } 
        }
    }
}
```

I tried numerous options in the "if" conditional, for example just a few like:

```
if (inputField.text > "0" || inputField.text < "350")
if (inputField.text >= 0 && inputField.text =< 350)
if (inputField.text >= "0" && inputField.text =< "350")
```

Same goes for the "else" conditional.

```
} else {
    if (inputField.text > "350") {
```

Maybe some one can point me in the right direction.

Comment: In what **line** of the code does the error occur?

Comment: @navnav Did not see your reply until just now! It is fixed now, but still thanks for your willingness to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (int(inputField.text) > 0 && int(inputField.text) < 350)    {
  outputField.text = xmlData.prefix_list.country[Number(inputField.text)];
  outputField.setTextFormat(myTextFormat);
} else {
  outputField.text = "DOES NOT EXIST";
  outputField.setTextFormat(myTextFormat);
}
```

You have to convert value to int if you are working with integers.

It's easy to convert between types in AS3. Here is tutorial how to convert String to Number http://www.trainingtutorials101.com/2011/01/actionscript-3-convert-strings-to.html

Comment: one tiny hint unrelated to the casting issue: You can set `outputField.defaultTextFormat = myTextFormat;` once when the text field is created rather than calling `setTextFormat` multiple times

Comment: WOW!!! That was FAST guys!!! Thanks so much, IT WORKS LIKE A CHARM! RESPECT.......

Comment: @ George Profenza: thanks for the hint, I implemented it and it work perfect, too! I learned a lot in the past few minutes from both of you. Greetings and respect from my side!!

Comment: If you're dealing with user input, you may want to use `parseInt(val) ` instead of casting `int(val)`, as it will take into account white space.

Comment: @LondonDrugs , thanks for the input. I will look into your suggestion!